# What would cause a wired vs wireless speed difference of 16mbps vs 9 mbps?

Tags: router, ethernet, wifi

Tested via speedtest.net

I've set my wireless router to be b/g/n mode (there's no n-only mode on my router).

And I am using a USB stick (N, not G) on on PC and an internal wireless on another laptop running XP Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several factors that can cause a speed difference between wireless and wired.  Several common factors include environmental factors such as electrical interference, other wireless clients communicating with the same wireless device, and distance from the router.  It is important to understand that the wireless media(air) is a shared resource and can have collisions requiring retransmission of data.  This retransmission will cause the network to slow as the same data must be sent again.

Comment: Speed being cut to half? That much difference?

Comment: It can be that much yes.

Comment: Anything obvious I can check to eliminate some 'easy stuff' ?

Comment: honestly it is hit or miss.  Sometimes something will help greatly(turning off unneeded electronics), other times nothing makes a noticeable difference.  It could also be your network connection was congested at the time.  To many variables to really suggest anything specific.

Comment: @user1008636 -Plugged in to the router directly I get 120Mpbs internet. Over Wireless-N or G 2.4Ghz I get about 1Mbps (crowded spectrum). Over Wireless-N 5Ghz I get 100Mbps (almost empty spectrum). Wireless is hugely dependant on so many factors, whereas being plugged in to the router is not.

Comment: fwiw I also did a wireless scan of my house, there were 8 neighbouring AP's using Channel 11, 2 on Channel 7 and 2 on Channel 5. My router came defaulted to Channel 11, making the wifi almost useless. Changing it to Channel 9 made a significant difference.